# Same query but different execution plans, same server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a copy of a table with the same indexes in the same database of the same server.
Then it executes the same query in one table and in the other but the execution plan is different.

Why?

These are my queries:

```
select top 1 * from SFMatl
where AppUpdated = 0 and UpdLock = 0 and CompanyId = 'ent'
order by recid

select top 1 * from SFMatl_Backup20042017
where AppUpdated = 0 and UpdLock = 0 and CompanyId = 'ent'
order by recid
```

And these execution plans:

[Query1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9x6W.png)

[Query2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5CYv.png)

My create tables:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SFMatl_Backup20042017]    Script Date: 20/04/2017 14:40:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SFMatl_Backup20042017](
    [RecId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [PrOdId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [OprNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [WrkCtrId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SizeId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SizeId2] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ColorId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [MatlPropId] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [LineNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SubForLineNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SerialNum] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [PalletNum] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [BatchNum] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [PQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [PUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [SUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [TUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [StkQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [StkUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FtQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [LbQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [MQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [KgQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [Yield] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [YieldUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WPQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [WPUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WSQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [WSUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SetNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LaneNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [RowNum] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TranType] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WasteId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Shift] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ShiftTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ShiftDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PRGCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [UserRemark] [text] NOT NULL,
    [JobType] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WareHouseId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [LocationId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AppUpdated] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [OnOffUpdated] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [InventTransId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [OrgSerialNum] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ReworkFlag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Reworked] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [GroupTranNum] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SystemCreated] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [OfflineTran] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UpdLock] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UpdLockTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SFBOMRevision] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UDF01] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UDF02] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AddEdit] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CalcGauge] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [MasterSerial] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [OprSerialCount] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [QACheck] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SpliceCount] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [NumAcross] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [PermitNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransAs] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [CreateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifyTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OSUser] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ComputerName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [Reassign] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Reassigned] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [OprCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SFMatl]    Script Date: 20/04/2017 14:40:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SFMatl](
    [RecId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [PrOdId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [OprNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [WrkCtrId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SizeId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SizeId2] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ColorId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [MatlPropId] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [LineNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SubForLineNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SerialNum] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [PalletNum] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [BatchNum] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [PQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [PUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [SUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [TUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [StkQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [StkUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FtQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [LbQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [MQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [KgQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [Yield] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [YieldUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WPQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [WPUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WSQty] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [WSUnit] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SetNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LaneNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [RowNum] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TranType] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WasteId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Shift] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ShiftTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ShiftDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PRGCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [UserRemark] [text] NOT NULL,
    [JobType] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WareHouseId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [LocationId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AppUpdated] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [OnOffUpdated] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [InventTransId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [OrgSerialNum] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ReworkFlag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Reworked] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [GroupTranNum] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SystemCreated] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [OfflineTran] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UpdLock] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UpdLockTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SFBOMRevision] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UDF01] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UDF02] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AddEdit] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CalcGauge] [numeric](28, 12) NOT NULL,
    [MasterSerial] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [OprSerialCount] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [QACheck] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [SpliceCount] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [NumAcross] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [PermitNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransAs] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [CreateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifyTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OSUser] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ComputerName] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [Reassign] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Reassigned] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [OprCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: The tables do not have the same data.  If they do, then the statistics probably differ.

Comment: Could you add the definition of each table? `CREATE TABLE ...` Maybe one table has a missing index on a column or so...

Comment: The tables have de same data, I don't understand...

Comment: I just put the definition of each table

Comment: Are indexes the same for both tables?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference with those queries is they are not the same.
The table SELECTed is not the same.

This means two things in term of Query Plan.
Different statistics due to different amount of datas for example.
Different indexes or index fragmentation.

You can check indexes and their fragmentation (and maybe rebuild/reorganize them if required), you can also recalculate the statistics.

If it still keeps the same query plans,
then the difference is mainly due to data contained in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

one of the main parameter ,sql server uses while creating a plan is statistics.So even if the data is same in both the tables you have ,statistics will be different,which leads to different execution plans

To view statistics for the tables ,you can use below

```
 dbcc show_statistics('SFMatl','AppUpdated')


 dbcc show_statistics('SFMatl','SFMatl_Backup20042017')
```

If you now,how to infer the above results, you will be able to see ,statistics are different for the above two tables ,which further decides plan quality